# Update clause in Audit Trail Trigger

Tags: t-sql, triggers, audit-trail

I got this trigger as a tip and I would like to know how it works with updates. It is supposed to create a record everytime there is an update or insert action on my main table.

```
create trigger tblTriggerAuditRecord on tblOrders
after **update, insert**
as
begin
insert into tblOrdersAudit 
(OrderID, OrderApprovalDateTime, OrderStatus, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn )
select i.OrderID, i.OrderApprovalDateTime, i.OrderStatus, SUSER_SNAME(), getdate() 
from  tblOrders t 
inner join **inserted** i on t.OrderID=i.OrderID 
end
go
```

From my understanding, it inserts all the **inserted** records to the main table to the stated columns in the audit including timestamp and user but how about the update? What if I update the rows in my main table? should not I have a joing also on the **updated** records?

Hope my question is clear, thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no table `updated` when a trigger is fired. In case of an update, the old values from your main table you'll find in a table `deleted` and the new ones are (like in case of an insert) in the table `inserted`.

That's the same as in this example:

```
UPDATE tabEmployee SET Salary = Salary * 1.05
OUTPUT inserted.EmployeeName, deleted.Salary, inserted.Salary
INTO tabSalaryHistory (EmployeeName, OldSalary, NewSalary)
```

In this example, every employee gets a salary increase. The value before the increase is stored in the output table `deleted` and the new value in `inserted`.

Have a look at [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/) for better understanding.

Comment: Ok, perfect diiN_ thanks a lot for explanation, I did not know that!

Comment: Done! :) Thanks again